# getting ligatures from other fonts via css

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts, font-face

What I am trying to achieve is to use one font, but only ligatures from a different font. My approach of doing this, is using the unicode-range-descriptor. So this is my css:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'ligature';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v21/nuFvD-vYSZviVYUb_rj3ij__anPXJzDwcbmjWBN2PKebunDXbtM.woff2) format('woff2');
    }

    @font-face {
        font-family: 'no-ligature';
        font-style: normal;
        font-display: swap;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/robotomono/v11/L0xuDF4xlVMF-BfR8bXMIhJHg45mwgGEFl0_Xvq_ROW4.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
    
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'no-ligature';
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/playfairdisplay/v21/nuFvD-vYSZviVYUb_rj3ij__anPXJzDwcbmjWBN2PKebunDXbtM.woff2) format('woff2');
        unicode-range: U+0066, U+0062;
    }
    
    li {
        font-family: 'no-ligature';
        font-size: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

As you can see in [this Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/cfa0179fe8604238b68b8e3c148e4faf?version=3.24.0), of course now all the f's and b's are substituted, and it shows not just the ligatures. There is no specific point in the unicode-table for ligatures, so how can I target only certain ligatures?

Thanks in advance for helping me!

Note: In [the Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/cfa0179fe8604238b68b8e3c148e4faf?version=3.24.0) i'm using a font which has no fb-ligature, *roboto mono*, and try to merge the fb-ligature of *play fair*. These fonts don't represent the actual fonts i'm using and are just for presentational purposes.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do what you're trying to do. Ligatures are a glyph-level mechanism, not a Unicode character-level mechanism. Using unicode-range the way you did, I would expect exactly the result you got. Why are you trying to automate this formatting? Or is this just an experiment?

Comment: The font we use will not have all the Ligatures we need and we are not allowed to change the font due to copyright. It is of great importance, that these Ligatures are visible since it's historical texts.
Seems to me then, that we have to wrap all ligatures in tags and then setting a custom-font with the ligatures we need... correct?

Comment: Yes, create spans (or some element) scoped to the character sequences in which the ligature should appear.